# Can we combine different yolov5 models trained of different classes into one?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, yolo, opencv

Suppose I've a yolov5 model trained on cars and second trained on bus and third trained on bike and so on. Is there a way through which I can combine all the model into a single model?
As by running all model it will take extra time.

Comment: you're asking what "transfer learning" is. -- you could maybe also do that without retraining at all, if all your nets only differ in the classification layers (the earlier ones are identical). then you could concatenate the classification layers.

Answer (score 1):

The process of using two or more models for inferencing one single data is carried out under `model ensembling` in YoloV5.

[Model Ensembling Tutorial](https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/issues/318)  clearly defines:

> Ensemble modeling is a process where multiple diverse models are created to predict an outcome, either by using many different modeling algorithms or using different training data sets. The ensemble model then aggregates the prediction of each base model and results in once final prediction for the unseen data. The motivation for using ensemble models is to reduce the generalization error of the prediction.

We can use:

```
python detect.py --weights yolov5x.pt yolov5l6.pt --data coco.yaml --img 640 --other-arguments
```

But the two or more models should be trained for the same classes only. Model ensembling can improve mAP and Recall during testing and inference.

As clarified in [issue#1188](https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/issues/1188)